# Using ICommand in Windows Workflow Custom Activities

Tags: c#, xaml, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have used Relay Commands quite a bit in `WPF` projects but I am currently working on Windows Workflows and I am making a custom activity with its own designer. I want a button on my design to add new fields if pressed. I have spent days trawling the internet but it seems windows workflow has defeated me. This is what I have and it does not work, if anyone knows why please help.

```
[Designer(typeof(MyCustomActivityDesigner))]
public sealed class MyCustomActivity : AsyncCodeActivity
{
    public MyCustomActivity()
    {
        AddSpecificParameter = new DelegateCommand(AddParameter);
    }
    public DelegateCommand AddSpecificParameter { get; set; }

    public void AddParameter()
    {
        //add value to an obervable collection
    }
}
```

Relay command implementation:

```
public class DelegateCommand :ICommand
{
    //Parameterless constructor needed as windows workflow serialises it
    public DelegateCommand()
    { }

    private readonly Action _action;

    public DelegateCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

And the xaml is simply a button with a command binding but due to windows workflow weird stuff it goes through ModelItem (at least for the other bindings I have)

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=ModelItem.AddSpecificParameter}"/>
```

So the key differences from code that I have in `WPF` apps that works is the parameter-less constructor but this shouldn't effect it? **Tested this, parameter-less constructor works fine in WPF apps,so it has to be due to the ModelItem not being able to handle commands?**

Also the ModelItem Binding path works for all the other bindable properties on the viewmodel (for example strings on labels)

Note: The activities are tested/displayed in a rehosted designer.

Comment: I think I found a solution to it, im running tests today so may post an answer tomorrow

Comment: found someone who has it working but he doesnt explain how he does it... at least we know its possible lol [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9fbed07c-b276-4629-be51-a15c09c50e40/communication-between-data-model-and-modelitem?forum=wfprerelease)